# ClassCastException: cannot be cast to org.apache.struts.action.Action

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I was experimenting with the Struts 1.3 and I added the mapping for Form and Action. I haven't implemented any code in the Action and I'm quite confused to see such an exception.

Thanks for your time.

**struts-config**

```
<form-bean name="ManageCarForm" type="form.ManageCarForm"/>
<action path="/manageCar"
            type="action.ManageCarAction"
            name="ManageCarForm"
            scope="request"
            validate="false">
        <forward name="ManageCar" path="user" />
</action>
```

**struts-tiles**

```
 <definition name="manage_Car" extends="default">
 <put name="body" value="/manage_Car.jsp"/>
```

**Empty Action class**

```
public class ManageCarAction  {

}
```

**FORM**

```
public class ManageCarForm extends UserForm {
    private String carIds;
    private List<String> model;
    // getters & setters

}
```

**manage_Car.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: action.ManageCarAction cannot be cast to org.apache.struts.action.Action
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear. An Action class must extend Action. And yours doesn't. But more importantly, why are you *experimenting* with a framework that is officially dead and left unmaintained for several years now?

Comment: @JBNizet maybe because there are still thousands of apps developed with struts that need maintenance ?